# Alexa Skill doesnt work with outbound API call

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

If I have the following code within my intent, everything is great...

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    let say = 'Hello. ';

    let slotStatus = '';
    let resolvedSlot;

    let slotValues = getSlotValues(request.intent.slots); 
    slotStatus = "I heard you say " + slotValues.query.heardAs;
    say += slotStatus;


    return responseBuilder
        .speak(say)
        .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
        .getResponse();
},
```

The moment I try to make an outbound call, I get an error, and I can not figure out why.

```
async handle(handlerInput) {
    
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    let say = 'Hello. ';
    let slotStatus = '';
    let resolvedSlot;

    let slotValues = getSlotValues(request.intent.slots); 
    slotStatus = "I heard " + slotValues.query.heardAs;
    
    const response = await httpGet(slotValues.query.heardAs);

    slotStatus = "I heard " + response.heard + " from the server.";
    say += slotStatus;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(say)
            .reprompt("try again. " + say)
            .getResponse();
```

},

the httpGet method is below...

```
function httpGet(query) {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
        host: 'www.hostname.app',
        port: 443,
        path: '/api/alexa.php?'+query,
        method: 'GET',
    };
    
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';

      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
}
```

Comment: if you run the httpGet code as a standalone function outside of your alexa function, what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

You should dig into the CloudWatch logs for your AWS Lambda for error messages.

Additionally, you can run and debug your skill locally with node.js, the ASK CLI, and a plugin for VS Code. I did a presentation a few days ago for the Alexa Community India group and walked through how to set that up and use it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xODwbsvisr4

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but the question doesn't really provide enough information just yet